# Laravel 5 Repository Json

Tags: json, laravel

Anybody help to me .I have custom pattern file.I can return my values on my controller but i can not return response json

my first ajax codes :

```
 $('.aa').keyup(function(){
        var form = $('#formc').serialize();
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data: form+"&deneme="+val,
            dataType:'json',
            url:"{!! URL::route('backend.category.deneme') !!}",
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            },
             error: function (request, status, error) {
               console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

And My Help Pattern file :

```
class CategoriRepository{
public function test($inputs) {
 return Response::json(['success'=>true,'data'=>'ekrsana bassın']);
}
```

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

just return a simple array like this.

```
class CategoriRepository{
public function test($inputs) {
   return ['success'=>true,'data'=>'ekrsana bassın'];
}
```

in your js

```
success:function(result){
  if (result.success == true){
    // your code here 
    console.log(result.data);
  } 
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

i cant return my dir :  respository/CategoryRespostory.php  :(

echo run it, but     return response(['status' =>  'success','data' => 'ddsdsad']); not work but controllers at working